# Laravel exists validation: Should not pass when user and product are already stored

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules

I have a `product_votes` table which stores for each user and product a value. The value can either be `1` or `-1` which is equal to an upvote or downvote. A user can only either up- or downvote a product and that only one time as user_id, product_id and value are unique.

But a user can change his vote. He can upvote a product and then downvote it afterwards, or the other way around.

Now I am trying to write a validation rule which checks whether the user has already upvoted a product or not. So, basically if there already exists a record with the value `1` for the specific user with the id e.g., `13` and the specific product with the id e.g., `5`.

For some reason, my validation does not work. The user always has the possibility to upvote a product multiple times. But I want the validation to fail and return a response with 'You have already upvoted this product.'

This is my validation in the `FormRequest` for a **downvote** (value -1) request:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'value' => [
            'required',
            'regex:/^[1]$/',
            Rule::unique('product_votes', 'value')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('product_id', $this->route('product')->id)
                ->where('value', -1)
        ],
    ];
}
```

The `value` `1` being sent via the transfer has NOTHING to do with the value being stored for the user and product in the votes table. This value is only needed to be able to execute a custom validation.

Do you guys know where my mistake is and what I did wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: I think you should not look at value to make the key unique. Your unique identifiers should be `user_id` and `product_id`, the `value` can be changed and should not spawn a new record. Something like `ProductVote::updateOrCreate(['product_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1], ['value' => 1]);` should work imo

Comment: ^^ Agreed. A vote is for a user and a product, regardless what the value is. To determine if the user voted just look at the two fields, user_id and product_id.

Comment: Where should I add the `ProductVote::updateOrCreate(['product_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1], ['value' => 1]);` line?

Comment: Step 1, remove `->where('value', -1)` from the validation rules. Also, remove `value` from `Rule::unique('product_votes', 'value')`. Step 2, use `updateOrCreate...` in your controller after the validation has passed.

Comment: Okay, but still: How will I be able to respond to my user that there is already an upvote stored if he wants to upvote a product again?

Comment: No need, make yourself life easier. Just return message telling "Provided value has been stored."

Comment: No, I especially want that message to be returned! Can you help me how I can do this?